# Autocomplete Google maps, devuelve latitud y longitud incorrecta

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-maps, google-api

estoy usando el autocompletado de google maps   y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

el proceso   es el siguiente:

1- el usuario ingresa en el input de autocompletado el lugar que desea encontrar.

2-de la lista despelgable que devuelve el servicio, el usuario selecciona la direccion  que desee.

3-a partir de la direccion seleccionada por el usuario, procedo a colocar un marcador en el mapa por medio de la latitud y longitud.

```
<input class="form-control valid" id="Address_Components"  
name="Address_Components" placeholder="Ingrese la dirección de su  
consultorio..." type="text">

<input class="latitud valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="* Debe marcar 
la ubicación del consultorio  en el mapa." id="Latitud" name="Latitud" 
type="text" value="" aria-describedby="Latitud-error" aria-invalid="false">

<input class="longitud valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="* Por favor 
Marque la ubicacion del consultorio en el mapa." id="Longitud" name="Longitud" 
type="text" value="" aria-describedby="Longitud-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

el script es el siguiente:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

//Autocompletado
var input = document.getElementById('Address_Components');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { componentRestrictions: { 'country': 'ar' } });


//Mapa
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_Consultorio"), mapaconfiguracion);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    console.log(autocomplete);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    console.log(place);
    console.log(place.geometry.location);
    console.log(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
    AgregarUbicacionActualAlMapa(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng())

    ///AgregarUbicacionActualAlMapa(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng())

    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
});







function AgregarUbicacionActualAlMapa(lat, lng) {
    var posicionactual = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    $(".latitud").val(lat);
    $(".longitud").val(lng);
    map.setZoom(16);
    map.setCenter(posicionactual);
    marker.setTitle("Mi consultorio");
    marker.setPosition(posicionactual);
    marker.setMap(map);
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    lat = $(".latitud").val();
    lng = $(".longitud").val();
    if (lat !== null && lat !== '' && lng !== null && lng !== '') {
        var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) };

        geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {

                if (results[0]) {
                    map.setZoom(16);
                    map.setCenter(latlng);
                    marker.setTitle("Mi consultorio");

                    CargarParcial_DatosDeUbicacion({ lat: lat, lng: lng });
                } else {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        window.alert('Primero seleccione su ubicación en el mapa con el marcador.');
    }
}
```

el autocompletado funciona perfectamente:
[image: autocomplete google maps]

sin embargo no me devuelve la latitud y longitud correcta(esa latitud y longitud me lleva a otra ubicacion que no tiene nada que ver ): 
[image: lat,long]

el marcador cae en la siguiente ubicacion(la cual es amenabar 1900 y no la direccion de sucre 3891)
[image: google maps]

¿Alguien me puede hechar una mano?

Comment: puedes pegar una imagen de donde cae la ubicación errónea?

Comment: @ffflabs actualice el post y pegue una imagen con la ubicacion del marcador. en mi opinion personals el servicio de autocompletado de google me esta dando mal las cooordenadas.

Comment: 1) De tu código, tal cual como está en estos momentos, le faltan: El mapa en tu código HTML, las propiedad iniciales del mapa (el objeto `mapOptions` que se define en la nueva instancia del mapa o con `setOptions`), y el componente `Marker` para el centro de tu mapa. 2) Como yo lo veo, no es que tengas las coordenadas incorrectas, es que estás trabajando con componentes de Maps que tienen distinto nivel de precisión. Haz lo siguiente: Busca la forma de ver los resultados que da geocodificar tus coordenadas obtenidas con autocomplete, a ver qué te da.

Comment: @CeAlCuadrado, te respondo a los puntos que pusiste 1)  si, solo puse el codigo necesario para que se entienda el problema. .    2) estoy usando el autocomplete de google , las coordenadas me dirigen a amenabar al 1900 cuando deberian ser los de sucre 3891. google tiene otros servicios que son mas precisos??? la verdad desconosco de ello.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando en Google Maps la ubicación que indicas en la imagen ("[Mariscal Antonio José de Sucre 3891, Buenos Aires, Argentina](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mariscal+Antonio+Jos%C3%A9+de+Sucre+3891,+C1430+BWK,+Buenos+Aires/@-34.5723799,-58.4718819,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x95bcb67a0e6abd51:0x4e544fce32514f22!8m2!3d-34.5723799!4d-58.4696932)"), se obtiene las coordenadas que indicas como erroneas al realizar lo siguiente:
Hacerle click derecho al punto rojo y presionar la opción "¿Qué hay aquí?" aparecerá una pequeña solapa en la parte inferior de la pantalla y al pie de la misma aparecerán las coordenadas de la ubicación marcada por el punto, las cuales son las mismas que indicas tu en la 2da imagen.

Comment: hola . las coordenadas que me devuelven son las siguientes: -34.572115,-58.469704 . estas coordenadas  son diferentes a las que me devuelve el servicio de autocompletado (ver imagen con coordenadas)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes razón, las coordenadas son muy distintas al lugar que corresponde.

Esta imagen es de una webapp tipo Arcgis que hice hace años, que tenía un buscador. Metí tu info en ella y me da el lugar correcto. Ahí puse los dos markers

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando mi código, que casi no entiendo ya (era joven y pobre en esa época *) veo que yo no ocupo el widget *excepto* para obtener la dirección formateada. Vale decir, cuando la persona hace click en la lupa o enter en la caja, compruebo que `getPlace` no me da vacío, y con la dirección escrita hago derechamente un geocoding con la clase google.maps.Geocoder

(*al menos lo joven se me pasó*)

Comment: Hola , Hago exactamente lo mismo. creo que debe ser un error del autocompletado de google. lo bueno que solo  fue una dirección al azar.                       En cuanto a lo de joven ,Bueno creo que de a poco nos vamos poniendo viejos todos jajaja